# looping over one column to get match and grab value from other columns

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have the following loop working.
It is giving me the volcanoes match: True or False, but I would like to bring other columns from the volcano19_20 dataframe also like: latitude, longitude, name if is True if its False it can be nan.

How to modify this loop to get not only True/False in volcanoes[].

```
volcanoes = []


for date in earthquakes19_20['date']:        
    volcanoes.append(date in volcano19_20['date'].unique() 
                     or date + timedelta(days=1) in volcano19_20['date'].unique()
                     or date + timedelta(days=2) in volcano19_20['date'].unique()
                     or date + timedelta(days=3) in volcano19_20['date'].unique())

earthquakes19_20['vol_match'] = volcanoes
```

sample of earthquake19_20 df:

[image]

sample of volcano19_20 df:

[image]

I have appended the earthquake19_20 with the volcanoes[] column (True/False) but would like to get also
Latitude[], Longitude[], Volcano name[] from the volcano dataset.
I hope this make sense.

desired output:

[image]

what I have right now is the part in bold and need the last 3 columns.

Comment: Post samples of `earthquakes19_20` and `volcano19_20` and your expected output.

Comment: @not_speshal I have added a sample of both datasets, what I am trying to achieve is to based on the date condition give me True/False column and then also bring Lat, Long and Volcano names to the earthquake dataset. I guess I can have 4 new pd.Series that I will convert to DF and then will concatenate with earthquake19_20

Comment: So if an earthquake happened, and then the volcano was within 3 days of the earthquake, you want that data? Your samples don't provide any matches

Comment: the samples don't have matches but there are matches, my loop is working and returned True/False pd.Series. At the end what I need is to have column volcanoes: True/False (which I have already), and then if True bring the value Lat, Lon and Volcano name. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: There is probably a better way to do this than looping. That's why it's better to provide more representative samples as well as your **expected output**

Comment: I need that as I need later to calculate the distance between earthquake and volcano based on the lat and lon.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243862/discussion-between-sylwia-kmiec-and-not-speshal).